# Como agregar jar externos aun war de proyecto Maven en eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

tengo una duda con respecto a como empaquetar jar a un war.

El proyecto ya lo termine de realizar pero use jar externos que los fui agregando en "ADD External Jars.." en el proyecto de eclipse, hice pruebas para ver si funcionaba el sistema web y note que todo iba bien, luego genere el war del proyecto y al llevarlo al servidor empezó a tronar todo ya que no encontraba esas librerías externas del proyecto, y por mi falta de experiencia no sabia el motivo.

Estuve investigando un rato y todos dicen que se debe instalar por medio de

```
mvn install: install-file -Dfile = -DgroupId = -DartifactId = -Dversion = -Dpackaging = -DgeneratePom = true
```

Mis dudas son las siguientes:

1. Entiendo que con esta linea instalo los jar a una carpeta m2, pero entonces estos aparecieran automáticamente cargados en el
   proyecto?
2. Al generar el war significaría que los jar externos instalados en la carpeta m2 se agregarían o se empaquetarían en el war y ya no tendría problemas al llevarlo a un servidor?

Espero me puedan ayudar, ya que soy nuevo trabajando con java y sus librerías. Graciasa todos

Answer (score 0):

Mi sugerencia es que verifiques o agregues la configuración de construcción del war:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Use this to include a selection of jars that will be included in the WAR -->
          <packagingIncludes>WEB-INF/lib/my-tag-library.jar,**/*.xml,**/*.properties,**/*.class,**/*.png,**/*.css,**/*.js,**/*.jsp</packagingIncludes>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Donde el tag `packagingIncludes` te da la opción de agregar las librerías externas a demanda.

Para mayor información podrías revisar esta guía oficial [Creating Skinny WARs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-war-plugin-2.3/examples/skinny-wars.html)

Comment: Hola sercheo_87 Hola, por lo poco que entendi  es que debo agregar en el proyecto web-info-lib los jars, y en mismo archivo del pom, al generar el war va agregar las librerias autmanticamente o copiar los jar dentro del war no? o sea que ya los jar estarian dentro del proyecto sin que esten aputando en un directorio especifico?

Comment: el agregarlos fisicamente no es necesario a menos que dichas dependencias no existan en el [Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com) aquí te dejo un repo de ejemplo [maven-war-plugin](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/maven-war-plugin.zip)

Comment: sercheo_87 Que tal sergio, en eso estoy de acuerdo, pero los jar estan modificados para que solo funcionen en la empresa, tienen algunas cosas modificados para evitar filtrado de informacion. Y por eso no puedo usuar las que estan disponibles por lo mismo